# how to retrieve contact data from engine (NOT MESSAGE)!

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

how to retrieve contact data directly from physic engine (not in a message).

I tried to use the map structure but this function also use messages.

```
sensors::SensorPtr sensor = sensors::SensorManager::Instance()->GetSensor(this->model->GetLink("0")->GetSensorName(0));

sensors::ContactSensorPtr contactSensor = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<sensors::ContactSensor>(sensor);

std::map<string, physics::Contact> contacts = contactSensor->GetContacts(this->contactSensor->GetCollisionName(0));

for (std::map<string, physics::Contact>::iterator iter = contacts.begin();iter != contacts.end(); ++iter)
{
       <<"count       " << iter->second.count <<endl
       <<"time        " << iter->second.time <<endl;
}
```

The probleme with messages, it may miss some data. I want that each time I run the simulation I get the same data sequence, but this is not the case. For instance look at this curves; data in the first run are different from the second even if its the same simulation [image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14456/how-to-retrieve-contact-data-from-engine-(not-message)!/) by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2016-09-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The solution is to use ContactManager classe

```
physics::ContactManager *contactManager =
 this->model->GetWorld()->GetPhysicsEngine()->GetContactManager();

for(int i=0; i<contactManager->GetContactCount(); i++)
{
    physics::Contact *contact = contactManager->GetContact(i);
    cout << "contact between "<<contact->collision1->GetLink()->GetName()<<" and "
    << contact-> collision2-> GetLink()->GetName() <<endl;          
}
```

---

Originally posted by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) with karma: 78 on 2016-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1